# GUI not showing symbols in Raspbian Jessie

Tags: raspbian-jessie, gui

I downloaded Raspbian Jessie (with Pixel) from [raspberrypi.org](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/) and installed it to my SD-Card via the `dd` command like specified in the installation guide.

Now I wanted to use the GUI, so after booting I typed in `startx`.
But the GUI doesn't work properly.  It doesn't show any icons or even the default background.

Here is a picture:

[image: GUI on startup]

The mouse works and I can open the programs in the bar above the cursor (but I don't even know how to access system settings or anything in a state like that).

How do I resolve this and properly start the GUI?

Setup:
Raspberry Pi 2 B 
Raspberry Pi Display V 1.1

Update:
My current hypothesis is, that either the image was corrupt or the SD-Card wasn't properly flashed.
I downloaded the image again and used `dd` with `bs=1M` instead of `bs=4M` and now it works as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess my SD-Card image was corrupt.

I downloaded Raspbian Jessie again and used the `dd` command with `bs=1M` instead of `bs=4M` to copy it to the SD-Card.
Now it works fine.